# How to get the last insert ID from a table

Tags: sql, db2

I want to get the value of the last ID insert in a table. How I can do this?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Well the solution that I use is:

```
select id from NEW TABLE (insert into (val1, val2, ...) values ('lorem', 'ipsum', ...))
```

This gets the id column from the last row inserted in the DB :)

Comment: For more information on this approach, see documentation on the [SELECT from INSERT statement](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.doc.relg%2Finsl.htm)

Comment: Tragedy. That "SELECT from INSERT" documentation either changed locations, or became unavailable.

Comment: Check section *Selecting inserted values* in your DB2 SQL Programming Guide. An example from my guide is

`SELECT EMPNO, HIRETYPE, HIREDATE
FROM FINAL TABLE ( INSERT INTO EMPSAMP (NAME, SALARY, DEPTNO, LEVEL)
VALUES('Mary Smith', 35000.00, 11, 'Associate'))`

Comment: [Selecting values while inserting data](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.apsg/src/tpc/db2z_selectvalueinsert.dita)

Answer (score 16):

```
SELECT IDENTITY_VAL_LOCAL() AS VAL FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
```

See [docs](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0004231.html).

Comment: This one worked for me but I needed to use OpenQuery to get it to work as we have the DB2 set up as a linked server. Hope that may help someone else

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this answer.

http://www.sitepoint.com/php-database-db2/

```
// get the last inserted ID into the specified table  
// int lastInsertID(string $tblName)  
function lastInsertID($tblName)  
{  
 if ($this->transIsOpen())  
 {  
   $sql = "SELECT SYSIBM.IDENTITY_VAL_LOCAL() AS id FROM " . $tblName;  
   $rs = $this->query($sql);  
   return $this->fetch($rs, "id");  
 }  
 return -1;  
}
```

OR this

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.db2-last-insert-id.php#98361

Answer (score -3):

```
int keyId = -1;
preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
resultSet = preparedStatement.getGeneratedKeys();
if (resultSet.next()) {
    keyId = rs.getInt(1);
}
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getGeneratedKeys()

Update: and don't forget to create preparedStatement with the following flag `Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS` otherwise it won't work)))

Comment: Uhmmm... Oracle != DB2

Comment: It's tutorial to java not Oracle

Comment: Then you are not addressing the OP's question at all.