# Get back the primary key value after insertion to db2 table by KeyHolder

Tags: java, database, db2, primary-key, auto-increment

Good day,

I have a table in db2, where the primary `is_autoincrement` is set to `Yes`. Means that everytime insert data to this table, no need to pass in the primary key value, because it will auto generate.

However, I need to get back the primary key value after insertion. The code is something as follow:

```
public integer insertRecord() {

    //insertion sql code here
KeyHolder keyHolder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();

PreparedStatementCreatorFactory factory = new PreparedStatementCreatorFactory(
                getInsertBatch2( ), new int[] { 
                        java.sql.Types.TIMESTAMP, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR,
                        java.sql.Types.SMALLINT, java.sql.Types.DATE,
                        java.sql.Types.INTEGER } );

int updated = JdbcTemplate.update(
                factory.newPreparedStatementCreator( params ),  keyHolder);

log.trace("key value is " + keyHolder.getKey( );

    //after insertion, return primary key
    return id;
}

private String getInsertBatch2() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder( );
    sb.append( "insert into " )
            .append( getDefaultSchema( ) )
            .append(
                    ".batches( startdatetime, type, manual, processdate, originalbatchid) " );
    sb.append( "values(?,?,?,?,?) " );
    return sb.toString( );
}
```

The insertion query is something as follow:

```
insert into table1(startdatetime, type, manual, processdate, originalbatchid) value (-- all the value here -- );
```

When I try to print out the keyHolder, it is null.

Kindly advise how to get the primary key.

Comment: Have you tried [`Statement#executeUpdate(String, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate(java.lang.String,%20int)) and [`Statement#getGeneratedKeys`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getGeneratedKeys())?  This will depend on the JDBC driver you are using as well

Comment: Answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3087836/db2-how-to-get-the-last-insert-id-from-a-table may help you.

Comment: Hi all, just edit my question. Kindly advise.

Comment: Your code currently has a compile error in it - you declare `updated` twice.  Fix your code first.  How often do you need to get changes to the default schema?  Are you logging people in based on their own id, or just using a connection default?  If the latter (second), you should be able to make all the prepared statement stuff instance variables, and not need to re-prepare the statement each time...

Comment: done fixed my mistake.

Comment: Hi @Clockwork-Muse, I done edit the compile error code. However, when I try to print out the `keyHolder.getKey( )`, it return null. Kindly advise on what mistake i make.